# What causes white blank images when shooting with a Canon PowerShot A4050?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting

I have a 3 week old Canon PowerShot A4050 camera. Almost all of my pictures (8 out of 10) are blank, white images. Video shooting is OK, but only occasionally good stills - does anyone know what can cause this?

Comment: Are you shooting in P mode? The shots sound over exposed.

Comment: Do you have exposure compensation on? If you over expose by 3-5 stops the picture might be very bright.

Comment: Definitely check EV compensation, but did you perhaps subject the cam to any serious physical impact? Sporadic photos followed by blank ones suggest faulty electronics.

Comment: if you could put online some samples (untouched, so that the EXIF data is still there), it would help. Exposure Compensation and faulty electronics are the likely suspects. EXIF data on a sample picture would help confirm what's going on...

Comment: you say 8 out of 10 are white, if the other 2 tend to be outdoor shots with sky in them this is a good indication you are overexposing your shots as people above suggested.

Comment: We really need some visual examples (preferably with EXIF metadata, as matt nguyen stated) to really help you. It is possible you are over-exposing, but EXIF will tell us that for sure.

Answer (score 1):

It's either a defective camera or the exposure is being set way too high (either by defective hardware or manual settings and user error).  If you can post samples of some of the photos that did come out as well as one of the ones that didn't, it might help.

If the images that came out were much darker scenes than the ones you took that came out white, it is probably user settings on the camera causing problems.

Try setting the camera to the mode with the little green square and make sure that the exposure compensation is set to 0 and see if you still have a problem as well.  If you don't, it is a user setting, if you do, then it is probably the camera.